I can't create liquidity pool on Raydium (JS)
I'm trying to create liquidity pool by Raydium(in JS @raydium-io/raydium-sdk)
But always Creating pool Transcation is failed for example: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/31NJnx7W3LYGAaaxmhxfs39UTLq124tyTAxkrpMET7822VFhZWqM3NRMv6aY8Pbi2vVsAdNwGDE2urJ3nuUSTYS2?cluster=devnet
Maybe there is no way to create raydium liquidity pool in devnet?
This my code: "main.cjs"
    console.log(walletTokenAccounts);
    const addBaseAmount = new BN(10000);
    const addQuoteAmount = new BN(10000);
    const startTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60*60 ;
    const poolId = await createPool({
      connection: connection,
      marketId: marketId,
      baseToken: {
        mint: baseTokenMint,
        decimals: Number(9)
      },
      quoteToken: {
        mint: quoteTokenMint,
        decimals: Number(9)
      },
      addBaseAmount: addBaseAmount,
      addQuoteAmount: addQuoteAmount,
      startTime: startTime,
      walletTokenAccount: walletTokenAccounts,
      wallet: fromKeypair
    });

And "create_pool.js":
async function createPool({connection, marketId, baseToken, quoteToken, addBaseAmount, addQuoteAmount, startTime, walletTokenAccount, wallet}) {
    const RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID = DEVNET_PROGRAM_ID;
    const myPublicKey = wallet.publicKey;

    console.log({
        connection: connection,
        programId: RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID.AmmV4,
        marketInfo: {
            marketId: marketId,
            programId: RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID.OPENBOOK_MARKET
        },
        baseMintInfo: baseToken,
        quoteMintInfo: quoteToken,
        baseAmount: addBaseAmount,
        quoteAmount: addQuoteAmount,
        startTime: new BN(Math.floor(startTime)),
        ownerInfo: {
            feePayer: myPublicKey,
            wallet: myPublicKey,
            tokenAccounts: walletTokenAccount,
            useSOLBalance: true
        },
        associatedOnly: false,
        checkCreateATAOwner: true,
        makeTxVersion: makeTxVersion,
        feeDestinationId: CONFIG_PROGRAM_ID.CREATE_POOL_FEE_ADDRESS
    })

    const initPoolInstructionResponse = await Liquidity.makeCreatePoolV4InstructionV2Simple({
        connection: connection,
        programId: RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID.AmmV4,
        marketInfo: {
            marketId: marketId,
            programId: RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID.OPENBOOK_MARKET
        },
        baseMintInfo: baseToken,
        quoteMintInfo: quoteToken,
        baseAmount: addBaseAmount,
        quoteAmount: addQuoteAmount,
        startTime: new BN(Math.floor(startTime)),
        ownerInfo: {
            feePayer: myPublicKey,
            wallet: myPublicKey,
            tokenAccounts: walletTokenAccount,
            useSOLBalance: true
        },
        associatedOnly: false,
        checkCreateATAOwner: true,
        makeTxVersion: makeTxVersion,
        feeDestinationId: CONFIG_PROGRAM_ID.CREATE_POOL_FEE_ADDRESS
    });
    const poolId = initPoolInstructionResponse.address.ammId;
    console.log(initPoolInstructionResponse)
    const { innerTransactions } = initPoolInstructionResponse;
    console.log(innerTransactions)
    try {
        const txids = await buildAndSendTx(innerTransactions);

    }catch (error){
        if (error instanceof SendTransactionError) throw error
        throw new SendTransactionError(error?.message, error)
    }
    
    return poolId
}

Also I'm trying to use another of solution:
https://github.com/Shiny0805/Solana-Token-Dist/blob/main/main.js
But There is the same problem...
Can you help me?

The error logs from that transaction might hint towards the solution. They say: "> Program logged: "Error: Init lp amount is too less(Because 10**lp_decimals amount lp will be locked)"". Maybe you need to increaseaddBaseAmount or addQuoteAmount?

It seems you're on the right track, though the transaction you shared indicated that there's issue with inital lp amount, which you specified as const addBaseAmount = new BN(10000); in your codebase.
You should multiply if with the decimal value of the token mint.
It should look something like this.
const addBaseAmount = new BN(tokenAmount).mul(new BN(10).pow(new BN(tokenDecimals)));

You might want to do the same for the quote token.
